# Erro intermitente de Session no CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Estou com um problema nos projetos que desenvolvo que intermitentemente gera um erro de session, porém o erro é somente quando o projeto está hospedado no servidor web (Utilizo o CPanel de uma revenda da HostGator).

Quando o erro acontece, se o usuário apertar "F5" ou simplesmente trocar de página(quando possível) o erro some, até hoje não consegui gerar o erro duas vezes ou mais seguidamente.

Segue imagens do erro.
[image: Erro que de vez em quando aparece no site ou sistema]

Segue imagem do código utilizado (encontra-se destacado no retângulo amarelo) quem é rodado e que possivelmente pode estar causando o erro.
[image: Código utilizado]

Url do site para que possam tentar gerar o erro: www.ravsistemas.com.br
**OBS.:** Para que eu consiga gerar o erro mais rapidamente eu costumo abrir o site em dois navegadores e em um dos navegadores eu fico trocando de página ou atualizando a página.

Comment: Copie o código e o erro e coloque na pergunta, fotos são difíceis de testar.

Comment: Erro semelhante com a solução nos comentários [CodeIgniter Session Error - Unlink Operation not Permitted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278597/codeigniter-session-error-unlink-operation-not-permitted)

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque o sistema não tem permissão de manipular o arquivo da sessão no diretório padrão tmp do sistema. Para corrigir configure a variável `$config['sess_save_path']` no arquivo `application/config/config.php` da seguinte forma:

`$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH.'cache/';`

Assim os arquivos de sessão serão salvos em `system/cache`

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar isso.

Comment: Ok. qualquer coisa é só falar

Comment: Eaí @RenanValenteRavSistemas, você testou?

Comment: Desculpe a demora, testei sim e até o momento não consegui gerar o erro.
Muito obrigado